# Need Help Deploying Simple WS WebApp into ServiceMix

Tags: java, osgi, jax-ws, apache-servicemix

So, I'm trying to deploy a simple Web Service webapp into ServiceMix.

SMX version: 5.4.0,
Java version: 1.7.0_75

**The code is located at:** https://github.com/yngwietiger/HelloWebService.git

My app contains 2 servlets: HelloWebService (exposes a simple web service) and MyServlet (very basic servlet)

I do a **mvn clean install** to build the war/bundle.

If I run **mvn tomcat:run**, it works fine, I can hit both servlets.

e.g. http://localhost:8080/HelloWebService/myservlet

and

http://localhost:8080/HelloWebService/helloWebService?wsdl

But when I deploy into SMX, I get the following error:

```
2015-04-27 10:14:11,155 | ERROR | pool-7-thread-1  | WebAppPublisher                  | ?                                   ? | 201 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 3.1.2 | Error deploying web application
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, pe/DatatypeConstants, have different Class objects for that type
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:141)[269:HelloWebService:0.0.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152)[269:HelloWebService:0.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:222)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:202)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1032)[72:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:422)[72:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:341)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:678)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, pe/DatatypeConstants, have different Class objects for that type
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1157)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    ... 34 more
```

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>jaxwsExample</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloWebService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloWebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/helloWebService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.webservices.demo.MyServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HelloWebService</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWebService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>JAX-WS webservice with maven</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>HelloWebService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <instructions>
                                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                                <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                                <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                                <Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                                <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                                <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                                <Web-ContextPath>/HelloWebService</Web-ContextPath>
                                <Webapp-Context>/HelloWebService</Webapp-Context>
                                <_wab>src/main/webapp</_wab>
                            </instructions>
                            <supportedProjectTypes>
                                <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                            </supportedProjectTypes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

All of the code is at the GITHUB link at the top, if anyone wants to try it.

If I comment out the WS servlet and listener, I can deploy in SMX and hit the simple servlet (MyServlet). But I just can't get the WS servlet to work.

Any thoughts/ideas?

I thought this would be easy, but it's a real pain.

I suspect it's something with my maven-bundle-plugin configuration, but I really don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's resolved. Just needed a newer version of jaxws-rt.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The plain jax ws from sun does not work very well in OSGi. You should try with Apache CXF.

See:
[Karaf Tutorial Part 4 - CXF Services in OSGi](http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/EoBk)

Comment: You know, I was just starting to wonder about that. I actually think I did a sample CXF service with no issues. I'll check out your link and try that out. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: As it turns out, I just needed a newer version of jaxws-rt.jar (e.g. 2.2.8 or 2.2.10).  Wish I had thought about that earlier. But the fact that it was working in Tomcat made me suspect it was something else. However, I did get it working with CXF as well. Thanks again.